# Creating a string and storing inside a variable and then accessing that string?

Tags: string, variables, store

I tried to store a string inside a variable and then call on that string to extract its value

```
txtboxname = ChkBox.Name + "Ans"
MsgBox (txtboxname.Value)
```

gives me an error 424 saying object required at the Msgbox line. `chkbox.name` is the name of a checkbox

Comment: Hello there. Can you tag the language you are coding in?

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].